# WPF MVVM Patern calculate Datagrid row column values

Tags: wpf

I want to calculate datagrid column values while user add rows

Here is my Code

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding SaleryDetailsCollection,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="640" Height="192" LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Observablecolloction like this

```
public ObservableCollection<SaleryDetailsModel> SaleryDetailsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _SaleryDetailsCollection; 
        }
        set
        {
             SalaryTotal = value.Sum(x => x.Amount);
            _SaleryDetailsCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SaleryDetailsCollection");
        }
    }
```

Here total sum of Amount column not calclulat on SalaryTotal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add and remove rows from an `ObservableCollection` it doesn't actually change the Collection instance, so your code won't get run.  There is an event on the collection called [CollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) that gets raised as rows are added or removed that you should hook.  You should be able to recalculate your totals in there.  It may just be easier to do the math inside the event that actually adds / removes rows though.

If SalaryTotal is a property that you are also binding on you may also have to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("SalaryTotal ");` after you recalculate it to get the UI to see the change if it isn't already done in your property setter.